# ios push notifications can only be tested with build uploaded to phone by cable

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, testflight

I'm working on with a push notification platform that's telling me that I'm getting a bunch of invalid push tokens from APNS.  Their best bet as to why this is happening is that APNS only considers builds that are uploaded to devices via cable as being in 'development' mode.  This wouldn't be a big deal, however, the push notification platform folk stop sending push notifications after they get three invalid tokens back from Apple.

If they're right, it means that even if I'm using TestFlight to do an ad hoc distribution, and using my ad hoc APNS provisioning profile,  the device considers the app to be in production mode.

That sounds crazy. I can't find anything about it in the Apple documentation listed below, so I'm a little suspicious.

```
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

```

Can anyone point me to documentation that shows that the only way for me to test that push notifications are working in my app is to physically attach the iOS device to my computer and run it via Xcode?

Comment: All that matters is how the app is signed. Apps signed with a development cert will only work with the APNS sandbox. Apps signed with a distribution cert (ad-hoc or distribution) will work with production APNS. It doesn't matter how you distribute your app. TestFlight is fine.

Comment: If you build the app with a cable (i.e. with a development profile) then the push notifications should still work.  However, if you don't sign with the adhoc APNS certificate, then when someone downloads the app via test flight, they will not get the push notifications.  Similarly, when you submit your app to the app store, push notifications will only work with the app specific distribution certificate.  Parse gives a very good explanation of everything you need to do in section 7 of: https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

Comment: Is this still true while you now submit the app to TestFlight signed with the certificate of production?